# What is the origin of the term catkin?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am curious about the meaning and/origin of the term catkin. The best I could find was dutch slang for a little cat.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/327911/what-is-the-origin-of-the-term-catkin?/) by [dfarning](https://answers.ros.org/users/19719/dfarning/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-08**:\

> The best I could find was dutch slang for a little cat.

I happen to be Dutch and I've never heard anyone use *catkin* as slang for a small cat.

The wikipedia page on catkin does say:

> The word catkin is a loanword from the Middle Dutch katteken, meaning "kitten"

are you referring to this? A loanword is hardly something I would call *slang* though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a reference to Willow Garage. From the [overview of catkin](https://wiki.ros.org/catkin/conceptual_overview#Overview)

> The name *catkin* comes from the tail-shaped flower cluster found on willow trees -- a reference to Willow Garage where catkin was created.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1